# Technical term for Internet-like network?

Tags: terminology, internet, computing

There is a computer network, similar to Internet in architecture but not connected to actual Internet, that is used by the military. What is the term to describe such network?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classified_United_States_website

Comment: What's wrong with "network"?  Or, to be a little more specific, "digital data network"?

Comment: [*"The Internet standards community historically differentiated between the Internet and an internet (or internetwork), treating the former as a proper noun with a capital letter, and the latter as a common noun with lower-case first letter. An internet is any internetwork or set of inter-connected Internet Protocol (IP) networks"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization_of_%22Internet%22) -- I find this worthy of mention but not of an answer, as it seems unlikely for the typical reader to be familiar with this usage.  "An (lowercase-i) internet" is theoretically correct but not common.

Comment: An "internal" network using the IP/TCP-stack of protocols - the same used by the Internet - is usually called an "intranet".  As for the military, I think they just kept the old name after disconnection it from the rest of the Internet - so it would be DARPA-or ARPA-net... or perhaps "MilNet" or something.  (Defense)AdvancedResearchProjectAgency is (was?) a part of the military devoted to research, and Internet sprung from a project for creating a network that couldn't be "knocked-out" by nukes - DARPA-net - when they allowed civilians to connect.  They invented the IP/TCP-protocol stack.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A private network that is accessible only to the employees of an organisation is called an *intranet*.

Definition: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intranet

> a computer network with restricted access, as within a company, that uses 
>   software and protocols developed for the Internet.

The same definition would apply in the military context. The difference might be that an elevated level of security precautions is imposed on such a network.

Comment: "Secured intranet" (encrypted, high-reliability, *et alis*)

Answer (score 7):

An internet is any TCP/IP network. When used within a single organisation, it is called an intranet. The Internet is simply the public TCP/IP network that hosts the World Wide Web.

Comment: WWW is only one part of the Internet, not the whole thing.

Comment: "The Internet is simply the public TCP/IP network that hosts the World Wide Web." would be better wording IMO.

Comment: This; so much this. "Internet" is so commonly used to mean "_the_ Internet" now that most people (IME) don't realise "internet" is a technological thing in its own right.

Answer (score 7):

[Wide area Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network) or WAN.

From Wikipedia:

> A wide area network (WAN) is a telecommunications network or computer network that extends over a large geographical distance. Wide area networks are often established with leased telecommunication circuits.
>
> Business, education and government entities use wide area networks to relay data among staff, students, clients, buyers, and suppliers from various geographical locations. In essence, this mode of telecommunication allows a business to effectively carry out its daily function regardless of location. The Internet may be considered a WAN.

Comment: A Local, Campus, or Metropolitan Area Network (LAN/CAN/MAN) could equally be described as "similar to [the] Internet in architecture" yet not meet the subjective ("over a large geographical distance") criterion of a WAN.

Answer (score 0):

A description of the evolution of

> ARPANET -> MILNET -> DDN -> SIPRNet (and NIPRnet)

can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPANET).

[Secret Internet Protocol Router Network (SIPRNet)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIPRNet) is the secure network.

Or possibly you mean the

> [Defense Information Systems Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_Information_Systems_Network)